# JSON extract only first element in array no matter what my filter in query is

Tags: sql, mysql, arrays, json, json-table

so in the column country has two data which in json ["AX", "JP"], i want to display country 'JP' because my query says DESC. But result display is 'AX' which is wrong because its supposed to display 'JP'. This is because in my query i put $[0], so no matter what my filter in query it will always display the first element in this json ["AX", "JP"] where 'AX' is 0 in array. So how should i fix this dollar part $[0], so i can filter my data.

this is the data for passport column , inside this passport column has country data

```
[{"status": 1, "country": "AX", "issued_date": "2022-07-05", "passport_no": "ABS123433NEW3", "expiration_date": "2000-06-07"}, {"status": 1, "country": "JP", "issued_date": "2022-05-01", "passport_no": "TK84773812NEW3", "expiration_date": "-"}]
```

this is the query

```
LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
      employees.id AS emp_id,
      JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(employees.passport, '$[0].country')) AS latest_passport_no
    FROM
      TAL.employees
    WHERE
      JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(employees.passport, '$[0].country')) IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY
      JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(employees.passport, '$[0].country')) DESC
  ) AS latest_passports ON EMP.id = latest_passports.emp_id
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: mysql  Ver 8.0.34 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: Can you please give a full sample of data from `employees.passport`?

Comment: okay, i already add it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) to extract all the `country` values from the `employee.passport` data. These can then be sorted descending and the "latest" value returned:

```sql
SELECT e.id, MAX(jt.country) AS latest_passport
FROM employees e
JOIN JSON_TABLE(e.passport,
  '$[*]' COLUMNS(
    country VARCHAR(2) PATH '$.country'
  )
) AS jt
GROUP BY e.id
```

Output for your sample data:

```
id  latest_passport
1   JP
```

Demo on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/YuLy7n55)

Comment: @imnfrhn I'm wondering why you chose to unaccept this answer? Was there a case where it didn't work? If so, if you update your question with that case I'm sure the answer can be modified to resolve the problem.